# NumPy/SciPy with MKL on OS X 10.11.6

Tags: numpy, scipy, intel-mkl

Does anyone else have instructions for getting the current (as of July 2016) versions of MKL and NumPy/SciPy working together on OS X?  I've tried the suggested flags in the site.cfg, but the build ends up compiling against the Accelerate framework instead of MKL.  Also, I'm using clang and MacPorts gfortran.

Comment: anaconda ships numpy/scipy with mkl by default.

Comment: So I've heard, but a lot of my current setup relies on the MacPorts installation, and I'm leery about switching everything over.